# Sum of SQL table rows with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

There is a table in a SQL database like below :

SampleTable :

```
-----------------------
 id | number | price 
-----------------------
 1  |   3    | 300
 2  |   1    | 200
 3  |   5    | 100
 4  |   10   | 10
 5  |   30   | 30
 6  |   1    | 500
-----------------------
```

I wanna calculate total price like below :

```
in each row => var SumOfEachRow = number * price;
Total Price = sum of SumOfEachRow;
```

Thus the `Total Price` would be 3100.

Now , I wanna calculate it with LINQ.
e.g :

```
int TotalPrice = from q in SampleTable
                 select new
                 {
                    TotalPrice = q.number * q.price 
                 }.Sum();
```

the upside code returns the wrong result !!!
Could you please guide me ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
decimal TotalPrice = SampleTable.Sum(q => q.number * q.price);
```

Comment: I've tested it before, It return an exception `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`

Comment: That's because you have sold a great deal of items ;) Try declaring `TotalPrice` as a `double` or a `decimal`. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: I tested `double`, but I receive the Exception again. I've done it with foreach.`var query = SampleTable.Select(q=>q); foreach (var item in query) TotalPrice += item.number * item.price` it doesn't return an exception !!!

Comment: `q.price` must be a `decimal` then. Try with `decimal TotalPrice`.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  var TotalPrice = from q in SampleTable.AsEnumerable()
                         let y = Convert.ToInt32(q["number"]) * Convert.ToInt32(q["price"])
                         select y;

      int totalPrice =  TotalPrice.Sum();
```

Comment: Well, it's the same response like previous answer!!! what's the difference !!! in the other hand `SampleTable` is Enumerable by default.